# this is not valid bitmap file when use GetObjectAsync download in aws S3 in .net core

Tags: .net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, amazon-s3

I have used `GetObjectAsync` method to save the file in `AWS S3` to a folder in the computer but when I downloaded [Error when open the image when I open it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6LCg.png)

Here my code:

```
 using (var response = await _client.GetObjectAsync(request))
            using (var responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                var title = response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-title"];
                var contentType = response.Headers["Content-Type"];

                Console.WriteLine($"Object meta, Title: {title}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Content type, Title: {contentType}");
                responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var createText = responseBody;
            File.WriteAllText(PathAndFileName + keyName, createText);
```